# Will taking no courses from physical sciences as an undergrad affect my chances of going to grad school for mathematics in the US?

Tags: graduate-school

I have been admitted to a 4-year B.S. in Mathematics program in an Asian country. The mathematics courses are excellent and at par with the finest universities in the United States and there will a generous number of courses from the humanities. All the same, there is a provision for taking 7 more single-semester courses, to get a minor (alternately, I could dabble in many other subjects other than math).

I was wondering if taking a total of 7 courses in English and Economics instead of courses like physics, chemistry and biology could seriously affect my application when I apply to grad school in the US for PhD in mathematics. I would almost certainly apply to  good grad schools like UChicago and Berkeley depending on my interests.

> Will taking no courses from physical sciences as an undergrad affect
>   my chances of going to grad school for mathematics in the US?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're applying to a *pure* math program, then it's unlikely that graduate admissions boards will be expecting courses in a particular outside discipline. If you're doing *applied* math, however, it would be much more logical to expect to see *some* coursework in an outside discipline.

However, economics may be suitable as an "outside" discipline if you're taking advanced coursework with a mathematical bent to it.

But overall, demonstrating that you are a strong candidate will make a much bigger impact than the specific training you have. Research experience, a strong statement of purpose, and great letters of recommendation will increase your chances of admission much more than if your "off-subject" courses are in economics or physics.